# Можно ли wmi список собрать в едино?

Tags: c#, wmi

Пытаюсь собрать всё максимально компактно.

Приведу пример:

```
private readonly static ManagementObjectSearcher Processor = new 
ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

private readonly static ManagementObjectSearcher OperatingSys = new 
ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

ManagementObjectCollection ProcG = Processor.Get();
foreach (var cr in ProcG)
{
   stringbuilder.AppendFormat(cr["Name"]).ToString())
}

ManagementObjectCollection OperaSys = OperatingSys.Get();
foreach (var z in OperaSys)
{
  stringbuilder.AppendFormat(z["SerialNumber"].ToString());
}
```

И.т.д .. Но код вышел очень длинным))

Можно ли как-нибудь объединить их?
Допустим в `List<string>`? или вообще что лучше использовать?

Думал сделать так для начало как-то:

```
var collectionWmi = 
{ 
 "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", 
 "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem",};
```

и.т.д и уже с ним работать, но я в сомнениях)

Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то давно в институте нам вдалбливали на лабораторных работах по информатике, что любую программу можно разделить на этап сбора данных (чтение пользовательского ввода), её обработку и вывод на экран данных.

Если бы у вас не было бы такого маниакального желания смешать все эти фазы в одну, чтобы сразу и читать и загонять в стринг билдер -- то вы бы увидели много вариантов по объединению похожих чтений полей.

А вы думаете в терминах строк. Соберите данные в класс и представьте, что у вас не один формат, а много форматов и отделите в голове СБОР инфы от ФОРМАТИРОВАНИЯ и ВЫВОДА.

Я бы сначала бы объявил класс Machine и сказал бы что у него есть prop Processors[] и остальная ваша портянка свойств. Не строки, а строгие типы.

Потом бы взялся за упрощение сбора информации. И отдельно бы думал о выводе информации в нужных видах.

Вы например не думаете, что у вас на одной закладке приложения могут показываться лишь данные о процессорах, а на другой -- об оперативке? И что каждый раз нужно лишь часть инфы выводить, а не сгребать всё попало в строки.

Вы думаете в терминах процедурных языков, у вас по сути одна длиннющая функция.

А разбить это на десяток классов, у каждого из которых будет по 10 строк кода, каждый из которых инфу по своему свойству заполняет. Процессор - о процессоре, ОС - про ОС. Увидел бы, что каждый лезет в ManagementObjectSearcher и выполняет по сути типовые операции, вынес бы это в базовый класс...

> Подскажите, на данный момент я использую stringbuilderи собираю все
>   данные через strbuild.AppendFormat("",path);, Думаю за место билдера
>   использовать List он может добавлять такие же строки через
>   запятую?

Вы по-прежнему не можете отделить в голове *способ хранения информации* от *формата вывода*. Хранить строки можно разными способами, ничего не мешает использовать List, можно хранить в Array, можно в свойствах класса. Причём вы, проектируя своё приложение вы можете как скрывать детали реализации, так и наоборот активно использовать знание о способе хранения.

А вывод информации через запятую -- это только один формат, который совершенно не зависит от того, что у вас внутри - список или массив.
В конкретной реализации у вас и для списка и для массива будет одно и то же:

```
var options = new[] { "first", "second", "third"};
var display = string.Join(",", options);
```

Тут два момента. Во-первых, замена стринг билдера на джойн ничего не меняет концептуально: меняете шило на мыло, а архитектура как была "трудоноподдерживаемый спагетти-код" -- так и осталась. Во-вторых, стринг билдер лучше, чем склейка строк: вряд ли вас интересуют копейки производительности (у вас в приложении есть множество мест, которые на порядки больше съедают ресурсов), но всё же если вы вспомните, что строки в c# -- неизменяемые объекты и сто раз делая склеивание строк вы сто раз создаёте новые объекты, в которые помещаете данные. В общем-то стринг билдер как раз и нужен в случаях, подобных вашему.

И ещё. Какая разница, как форматировать строки? Может быть вы завтра захотите свою программу сделать веб-приложением -- и не будет у вас ни стринг билдера, ни склейки Join'ом -- а будет у вас Razor и он будет строить `<ul>` список из вашего List'а.

Comment: @A K, Может я немного не понял)) За совет спасибо, но я имел ввиду что хранение в List<string> не допустим 2/4 аргументы. Пример  
`List<string builder = new List<string>`  далее я добавляю каждую запись `builder.Add("Text<html>",cr["Name"]).ToString())` каждый раз я добавляю 2 аргумент в `builder.Add` через запятую *,* Объясните как это работает?!

Comment: @ArteS А это работает? Я ещё тогда хотел спросить, откуда вы код копируете -- ведь он же неработающий. И в этом две ошибки, код не скомпилируется, т.к. нет перегрузки метода `Add`, принимающего два аргумента. Может быть вы ищете что-то типа `builder.Add(string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", cr["Name"]));` или `builder.Add($"<div>{cr["Name"]}</div>");`? А потом уже разворачивать полученное через запятую? (Ну, тут тогда не нужно в div оборачивать, представьте что там не div, а span)

Comment: @A K, попробовал Ваш способ, он мне на выходе матерится `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.String]` записываю 
 в файл так `bulder.ToString();`

Comment: @A K, решил проблему: изменил метод записи.  `File.WriteAllLines(pathtosave, bulder);`

Answer (score 1):

Я бы каждый WMI запрос обернул бы собственный тип.

Получится, что в коде не будет каши и будет соблюден принцип "разделяй и властвуй".

Так же результаты каждого запроса будут типизированны, так как вы загоните их в собственный тип.

Затем бы переопределил метод `ToString()`, что бы все возвращалось в виде название поля-значение.

А уже вот эти маленькие классы объединил бы в более общую сущность SystemInfo, где бы были перечислены эти типы.

В `SystemInfo` добавил бы метод `GetReport()`, который бы вызвал `ToString()` у каждого поля и вернул бы единую строку.

Comment: Интересно) Попробую, а вот если бы Вы дали пример))

Comment: Подскажите, на данный момент я использую `stringbuilder`и собираю все данные через `strbuild.AppendFormat("",path);`, Думаю за место билдера использовать `List<string>` он может добавлять такие же строки через запятую?

Comment: @ArteS Дописал в свой ответ про List.